# How to efficiently detect language for a string on python list?

Tags: python, language-detection

I've been trying with langdetect however my results aren't satisfactory. Please see below:

```
from langdetect import detect   
myText = ['something like this', 'hello, I hope', 'bonjour', 'guten tag', 'hola amigos']

languages = []

for x in range(len(myText)):
    languages.append(detect(myText[x]))
```

languages variable returns:

```
['en', 'en', 'hr', 'sv', 'so']
```

Could someone recommend a more efficient way to detect string language for my scenario above? Thanks!

Comment: Your text snippets are too short to perform well.

Answer (score 5):

You simply don't have enough text to detect the language correctly. Check the probabilities reported by the `detect_langs` method:

```
from langdetect import detect, detect_langs
myText = ['something like this', 'hello, I hope', 'bonjour', 'guten tag', 'hola amigos']

languages = []

for text in myText:
    languages.append((text, detect_langs(text)))

print(languages)
```

Gives:

```
[('something like this', [en:0.7142843359964415, no:0.2857134272509894]), 
('hello, I hope', [en:0.5714282536622661, it:0.42856936839505744]), 
('bonjour', [hr:0.4285730214431372, sq:0.28571322755605805, fr:0.2857129560702645]),
('guten tag', [sv:0.999995044011124]), 
('hola amigos', [so:0.9999965325258])]
```

See how the results for `bonjour` are mixed - no language has a concrete lead over others.

Now if I add just a little more text to that example:

```
from langdetect import detect_langs

print(detect_langs('Bonjour, mon ami'))
```

That gives:

```
[fr:0.8571383531700392, sq:0.14285710967856416]
```

Which is a lot more accurate.

So to answer your question: ***get more data***

Comment: Funny how Google Translate refuses to translate "bonjour" if you set the language to Croatian, though. Likely `langdetect` works with engrams.

Answer (score 2):

It gives you exact result but in [ISO 639-1 code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes) short format of languages. You can use a dictionary to map these short codes to their corresponding broad language name like :

```
language_dict = {'en' : 'english', ...}
```

For alternatives, you might check out [textblob](https://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/api_reference.html#textblob.blob.BaseBlob.detect_language) :

```
from textblob import TextBlob
b = TextBlob(myText[2])
b.detect_language()
# output : 'fr'
```

For `myText` list the corresponding result given is :

```
['en', 'en', 'fr', 'de', 'es']
```

Comment: I think the OP is not so much concerned with the iso codes instead of full names, but more with the result that e.g. `"bonjour"`  is detected as Croatian.